# How to Define an element in ruby (watir) with parent div and combining 2 different variables for div id? (selenium)

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver, ui-automation

I'm trying to define an element for an automated test using ruby + selenium.
The element has 3 attributes I'm trying to combine. 1st, a parent div, 2nd, an ID, and 3rd, a name. The Id and name I must combine to create a unique ID that the element should be able to be called by.
So...
Element = (ID + Name) + parent div

Here is an example of the element:

This element id of "730_Test%Profile" is created when a new entry is created on the table on the page I'm automating. The ID# of 730 is one variable on the table in the page and "Test Profile" is another variable on the table on the page. They get combined together to create the element mentioned above. In attempting to define this element in ruby:

element(:edit) { | edit_name | browser.div(id:edit_name).parent.div(class:'editHolder') }
element(:id_value) { |id| browser.div(id:id)}

Where "edit_link" is just the name part (pointer set up to give "edit_link" value of name)
"id_value" is the ID part (pointer set up to give "id_value" value of the id)

I need to combine to create the element mentioned above. I cant call the element by its direct name because the full name "730_Test%Profile" is created while the automated test is running...so I have to piece it together while the test is running using the pointers from two different variables (Integer and String) to create the unique ID for this element. So far, these lines of code are not identifying the element correctly:

```
element(:edit_name) { | edit_name | browser.div(id:edit_name) }
element(:id_value) { |id| browser.div(id:id)}
element(:selection){browser.div(id:'@id + "_" + edit_name').parent.div(class:'editHolder')}
```

(element "selection" is the focus)

Comment: Where does `element` come from? Is this Cheezy's page object gem?

Comment: If you can derive the id, why do you also want to use the parent, editHolder, element?

Comment: Element comes from js table. I'm coding under the taza framework so this is a page file I'm attempting to define elements on. Also, I attempted to use the parent editHolder after my attempted to define the element with just the other two attributes failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to do:

```
element(:selection) { |id_value, edit_name| browser.div(id: "#{id_value}_#{edit_name.gsub(' ', '%20')}") }
```

This is creating a `selection` method that finds a div by id using the known/provided id and name.

The method would be called like:

```
id_value = 730
edit_name = 'Test Profile'
@site.your_page.selection(id_value, edit_name)
```